# Slow Scroll Toggle with no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know its a bit to ask, but is the following possible without using jQuery? I have it running with jQuery now but it seems to be presenting performance issues. If you could help I will be most grateful. I am not lazy, just not very code knowledgable. Took me a while to even get this far.

```
 //
    // default speed ist the lowest valid scroll speed.
    //
    var default_speed = 1;
    //
    // speed increments defines the increase/decrease of the acceleration
    // between current scroll speed and data-scroll-speed
    //
    var speed_increment = 0.01;
    //
    // maximum scroll speed of the elements
    //
    var data_scroll_speed_a = 2; // #sloganenglish
    var data_scroll_speed_b = 5; // #image-ul
    //
    //
    //
    var increase_speed, decrease_speed, target_speed, current_speed, speed_increments;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
            var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
                Div_one_top = $('#image-ul').offset().top,
                Div_one_height = $('#image-ul').outerHeight(true),
                Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
            if (WindowScrollTop + Window_height >= (Div_one_top + Div_one_height)) {
                $('#sloganenglish').attr('data-scroll-speed', data_scroll_speed_a).attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed).attr('data-speed-increments', data_scroll_speed_a * speed_increment);
                $('#image-ul').attr('data-scroll-speed', data_scroll_speed_b).attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed).attr('data-speed-increments', data_scroll_speed_b * speed_increment);
                increase_speed = true;
                decrease_speed = false;
            } else {
                $('#sloganenglish').attr('data-scroll-speed', '1').attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed);
                $('#image-ul').attr('data-scroll-speed', '1').attr('data-current-scroll-speed', default_speed);
                decrease_speed = true;
                increase_speed = false;
            }
        }).scroll();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any performance issue in your code, although there is space for some optimization. And I don't think jQuery might be the problem.

First thing to notice is the CSS access.
The height attribute is very expensive to access because it causes the browser to process many rendering steps of the pipeline, as you can see in [CSS Triggers](https://csstriggers.com/).

You are retrieving the height of two elements in a scroll event, which means that they will be calculated many times. Is it really necessary?

If your `#image-ul` element doesn't change its height, maybe you can calculate it outside of the event only once.

In the case of the window height, I believe it won't change in the scroll event. How about to create different handlers, one for the events that need to (re)calculate the window height and another for the events that don't need that calculation?

Another noticeable point is that you set the 'data-current-scroll-speed' and the 'data-speed-increments' attribute always with the same constant value. No change, no unset. Is it really necessary?

Actually, it is not clear what you are really doing. Your performance issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, @Rodrigo Pedrosa! You are making some good points! I will try to implement them and get back to you on the result.

Comment: Thanks again @Rodrigo Pedrosa. I am now attempting to retrieve the height of the two elements only upon load or resize. But I am not getting it right I think. See the code in my answer, please. Further: the #image-ul changes height responsively. Further: "Another noticeable point is that you set the 'data-current-scroll-speed' and the 'data-speed-increments' attribute always with the same constant value. No change, no unset. Is it really necessary?" This i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Please, @Rodrigo Pedrosa, may I ask you to adapt the code as you think it would be better?

Comment: What are you trying to do that is not working?
I believe you should calculate the window height only in the 'load resize' event. The other values must be recalculated on scroll, right?